# Asp.net jquery dropdown from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to load dropdown with Food Groups like Dairy and Egg Products , Fats and Oils when a Groups is clicked Foods should be loaded when Dairy is clocked all Chheeses should be loaded when I click on cheese the calorie should be displayed.Attaching same json file.In this example for Cheese paremesan low sodium 451 should be diosplayed

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Consumed.aspx.cs" Inherits="Weight.Consumed" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <title>METS APP</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setOption();
            $('#CategoryDDL').change(function () {
                setOption();
            });

            $('#Calculate').click(function Calculate() {
             
                var CALORIES = $("#DescriptionDDL option:selected").val();
               
           
                $('#result').val(CALORIES);
            });
        });

        function setOption() {
            $('#DescriptionDDL').html('');
            var DefaultOption = '<option selected  disabled>' + "- Select -" + '</option>';
            $('#DescriptionDDL').append(DefaultOption);
            var Category = $("#CategoryDDL option:selected").val();
            alert(Category); 
            if (Category != '- Select -') {
                $.getJSON('cons.json', function (data) {
                    for (var cons of data.consmaster.Consumed) {

                       
                        if (cons.GRP  == Category) {
                            var option = '<option value=' + cons.VAL + '>' + cons.DESCRIPTION + '</option>';
                            $('#DescriptionDDL').append(option);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>





<div>

    <h1>Consumed Calories</h1>
    
     <br />
    Activity: <select name="CategoryWgt" id="CategoryWgt">
        <option selected="selected" value="- Select -" disabled="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="100">Dairy and Egg Products</option>
         <option value="200">Spices and Herbs</option>
        <option value="300">Baby Foods</option>
        <option value="400">Fats and Oils</option>
        <option value="500">Poultry Products</option>
        <option value="600">Soups, Sauces, and Gravies</option>
        <option value="700">Sausages and Luncheon Meats</option>
        <option value="800">Breakfast Cereals</option>
        <option value="900">Fruits and Fruit Juices</option>
        <option value="1000">Pork Products</option>
        <option value="1100">Vegetables and Vegetable Products</option>
        <option value="1200">Nut and Seed Products</option>
        <option value="1300">Beef Products</option>
        <option value="1400">Beverages</option>
        <option value="1500">Finfish and Shellfish Products</option>
        <option value="1600">Legumes and Legume Products</option>
        <option value="1700">Lamb, Veal, and Game Products</option>
          <option value="1800">Baked Products</option>
        <option value="1900">Sweets</option>
        <option value="2000">Cereal Grains and Pasta</option>
        <option value="2100">Fast Foods</option>
           <option value="2200">Meals, Entrees, and Side Dishes</option>
        <option value="2500">Snacks</option>
        <option value="3500">American Indian/Alaska Native Foods</option>
        <option value="3600">Restaurant Foods</option>

    </select>
    <br />
    Description: <select id="DescriptionDDL"></select>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate">Calculate</button>
    <br />
    Calories in 100gms: <input name="result" type="text" id="result" />


</div>

</asp:Content>


{
  "consmaster": {
    "Consumed": [
      {
        "CODE": 42258,
        "GRP": 100,
        "DESCRIPTION": "Cheese product, pasteurized process, cheddar, reduced fat",
        "WEIGHT": 28,
        "VALMEASURE": 67.2,
        "VAL": 240,
        "MEASURE": "1 slice 1 oz"
      },
      {
        "CODE": 43340,
        "GRP": 100,
        "DESCRIPTION": "Cheese, parmesan, low sodium",
        "WEIGHT": 100,
        "VALMEASURE": 451,
        "VAL": 451,
        "MEASURE": "1 cup, grated"
      },
      {
        "CODE": 42117,
        "GRP": 100,
        "DESCRIPTION": "Imitation cheese, american or cheddar, low cholesterol",
        "WEIGHT": 113,
        "VALMEASURE": 440.7,
        "VAL": 390,
        "MEASURE": "1 cup, shredded"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed name="CategoryWgt" id="CategoryWgt"> to '#CategoryDDL' and it started working